# Not able to bind data in posts.hbs

Tags: ember.js

**templates/posts.hbs**

```
<h2>Posts</h2>
    {{#each model as |post|}}
      <div>
        <h3>{{post.postid}}</h3>
        <h3>{{post.title}}</h3>
        <h3>{{post.userid}}</h3>
        <h4>{{post.description}}</h4>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
    {{outlet}}
```

**serializers/posts.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType){
    payload = {data: payload};
    console.log(payload); //in console getting data here properly
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

**routes/posts.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    let posts = this.store.findAll('post');
    console.log(posts);
    return posts;
  }
});
```

Getting data from backend API point and printing data in console properly. Everything fine.
But not binding in handlebars (posts.hbs). Can someone help me with this? New to ember Js.

In **routes/posts.js** from console.log(posts) I'm getting one error

```
reason: EmberError
description: undefined
fileName: undefined
lineNumber: undefined
message: "Assertion Failed: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using blog-front-end@serializer:post:)"
name: "Error"
number: undefined
stack: "Error: Assertion Failed: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using blog-front-end@serializer:post:)↵    at new EmberError (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:30297:21)↵    at assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17992:13)↵    at Object.assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:30109:34)↵    at Class._normalizeResourceHelper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:89458:61)↵    at Class._normalizeDocumentHelper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:89413:25)↵    at Class._normalizeResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:89512:36)↵    at Class.normalizeArrayResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:90051:19)↵    at Class.normalizeFindAllResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:90021:42)↵    at Class.normalizeResponse (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:89997:48)↵    at Class.superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36019:22)"
__ember1605717703192: "ember449"
```

Comment: Can you share the output of the API? It seems like it doesn’t match what Ember Data is expecting.

Comment: Can you show your models/post.js file? Do you have one?